# Bin centers from recommended histogram function - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab now recommends to use the histogram in place of hist, however doesn't display an obvious way of finding the bin centers like the previous function.

My current code that works fine with the hist function:

figure

[counts171,position171] = hist(image171_reshaped,200);

plot(position171,log(counts171));

How would I be able to transform this piece of code in order to incorporate a recommended function such as 'histogram' or 'histcounts' in place of 'hist', while still obtaining the bin centers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`histcounts` returns edges instead of bin centers and bin centers are midpoints between consecutive elements of the edges. So using `diff` function bin centers can be obtained:

```
[counts171,edges171] = histcounts(image171_reshaped,200);

position171 = edges171(1:end-1) + diff(edges171) / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I tried something similar before but I couldn't get the resulting vectors the same length. Could you please explain what the first part 'edge171(1:end-1)' of the second line does please?

Comment: of course . assume that edges are : edges=[1 3 6 11] then bin centers are between [1 3] and [3 6] and[6 11] so if number of edges are 4 then number of bins are 3. then we require only first 3 edges to be added by difference between consecutive elements(diff). `end` means the end element of a vector and end-1 means one before the end element so 1:end-1 means all element of the vector except the end element